# How do I create a view in JetBrains DataGrip?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, datagrip

I am using an Azure SQL database with DataGrip. I would like to create a view connecting certain tables within my database.

Does DataGrip have a tool for doing this? If so, how can I do it?

It's relatively easy in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I would right click the Views folder and select 'New View...'

Comment: What's wrong with `create view ...`?

Comment: I was just looking for something with a UI. Does this exist in DataGrip?

Comment: For now DataGrip has no UI for creating views. Please, follow and share your thoughts: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-132

Answer (score 14, accepted):

UPD: in the late version there is a UI for creating a view:

[image]

---

Views can be also created via raw SQL. In DataGrip you can generate it automatically via *Generate* action (Alt+Ins, Cmd+N for OSX) where several objects for generation are available.

[image]

Comment: I wonder if that's relatively new. Either way, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

According to other users' comments this feature does not exist at the moment.